# Subscribing to BehaviorSubject throws error in Angular 8

Tags: angular, compilation, rxjs, behaviorsubject

Working on a Single Page Application in Angular 8 whereby am parsing some data from a component to a service, then in the service I subscribe to it using rxjs BehaviorSubject.on compilation on Angular CLI I get this error **src/app/Services/shared.service.ts(12,21): error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.**

Cant seem to locate what the issue is?

**shared service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { TokenService } from './token.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SharedService {

    //All children
    private children = new BehaviorSubject;
    checkAll$ = this.children.asObservable();

    childData(data:any){
       this.children.next(data);
    }

    constructor(private Token : TokenService) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BehaviorSubject` needs an argument. You didn't provide it.

```ts
private children = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Comment: Thanks alot,, Can you assist me on uploading an Angular project to Shared hosting via Cpanel,, It consumes a Laravel API..

Comment: @Martin If you post another question, I or any other SO users will try to help you

Comment: Please check the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912868/uploading-an-angular-8-project-and-laravel-on-shared-hosting) and assist where possible.. Regards